# User-based Management of Facebook Comment Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I would like to implement facebook comment plugin into a website. This website consists of users with facebook id numbers. I want that, every user can manage the comments in their profile pages.

In [Facebook comment plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), I found that, adding

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
```

leads the specified user can manage the comments. So, could it be a problem if I set this user id dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any update on this question? I am facing a similar situation.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about it, I gave up for now.