# Allow users to add disqus/facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, disqus

Imagine a tool that helps people to build their portfolios. As a part of it, the tool allows its users to add disqus/facebook comments widget on their portfolios so that people visiting their portfolios can comment on the portfolio.

From the tool perspective, It needs permissions/capability to host such a widget on the portfolio creator's behalf such that the portfolio creator can still do moderation around the comments posted; by either logging in to his disqus or facebook account.

How can I go about implementing such a thing?

An answer around integrating facebook comments plugin would be better as most people have facebook accounts.

**UPDATE:**

Disqus has widgets for platforms like Wordpress, Blogger etc. The situation is similar as I am trying to support a disqus widget for my app/platform so that each user of my app can add a disqus widget.

I found a similar question on SO:

[User-based Management of Facebook Comment Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326544/user-based-management-of-facebook-comment-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) plugin. (It's just suggestion. I havn't tried yet such scenario.)

Tough part I think is giving moderation to portfolio holder. I think under single application it will be harder to you to give them management permission. You will have to check is there possibility to give access rights of moderation to those users. (Or else you have create different application for each user.)

Or it might be possible to take settings from each portfolio holder. you will have to take user permissions and store it in your database. And then on each user page show comments page according to settings given by user.

See [comments plugin info](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/facebook-social-plugins/) .

Comment: Is this post helpful to you? Do you got appropriate solution? If yes, please post your solution. I would like to see accepted answer.

Comment: No, not really. The tough part is moderation. There still doesn't seem a way to allow users to moderate the comments plugin on their own facebook accout.

Comment: That's what I was saying moderation will be hard for your scenario. Have you tried 2nd option I have given to you? (That seems you are thinking same as like me.) Your scenario is really difficult to moderate.